# python - Trying to setup Pong. Having trouble with budget widget and hiding it

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid, widget

New python programmer here. Trying to figure out why my code makes me click the button twice before it hides the button. Also, how would I make it go to a new screen (pongGame)? Thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
def hideButton(event):
    event.widget.pack_forget()
def titleButtonClicked():
    print("Title screen button clicked")
    btn.bind('<Button-1>', hideButton)
    pongGame
root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
def pongGame():
    canvas.createline(50,100,250,200,fill="black",width=10)
btn=Button(root, text = "Start", command = titleButtonClicked)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to click it twice because that's how you've defined it to work. The first click calls `titleButtonClicked`. That creates a binding but doesn't call `hideButton`. So, `hideButton` won't be called until the user clicks again and your second binding is activated.

> Also, how would I make it go to a new screen (pongGame)?

That is way too broad to answer here. There are many ways to "go to a new screen". If what you're really asking is why `pongGame` doesn't seem to do anything, it's because you aren't calling it. If you want the function to be called you have to do `pongGame()` not `pongGame`.